# Why does torch print function insert horizontal tab?

Tags: lua, torch

I noticed the following with torch (7):

```
> lua -e "print(\"abc\")" | hexdump -c
0000000   a   b   c  \n                                                
0000004

> th -e "print(\"abc\")" | hexdump -c
0000000   a   b   c  \t  \n                                            
0000005
```

If I print a simple string with torch, there is an extra horizontal tab (`\t`) that gets inserted compared to calling lua directly.

Is there a specific reason for this behavior? Is there a way to turn it off? Or is this a bug?

Comment: why don't you ask the torch developers? I don't think you'll get more qualified answers here.

Comment: To follow up on this, I followed your advice and used what I believe is the "proper" channel and posted the same question on the Torch Google Groups. No response so far https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/tF1Mn7KwBTA

Comment: guess you have to be patient. maybe you'll never find out why it is like that. but chances are higher that someone there will know why than here.